# How to store a file in Laravel from its content

Tags: php, laravel, file-storage

I have the contents of an SVG file in a variable in my code, and I would like to store it using the documented [Automatic Streaming](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#automatic-streaming) method of Laravel (basically using `putFile` or `putFileAs` methods) in a remote AWS S3 bucket.

SVG content (QR code) is dynamically generated by a package, so I do not have it previously stored in the filesystem (do not have a path):

```
$svg_contents = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" ...';
```

The problem is Laravel's `putFile` and `putFileAs` methods only accept `Illuminate\Http\File` or `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` instances as arguments. From Laravel docs:

```
// Automatically generate a unique ID for filename...
$path = Storage::putFile('photos', new File('/path/to/photo'));
 
// Manually specify a filename...
$path = Storage::putFileAs('photos', new File('/path/to/photo'), 'photo.jpg');
```

Any thoughts?
In other words, I am asking for a smart way to avoid storing it temporarily in `local` filesystem and then remotely store it in S3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about  $path = Storage::put("photos/aaa.svg",$svg_contents);

Comment: The `put` method does not return the stored file path. You must provide it as an argument instead. So I would like to use specifically the `putFile` method as it automatically deals with unique filenames.